# Prevent Flex DataGrid mix events

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, flex4.5

I have the following code for my Datagrid:

```
    <s:DataGrid id="proveedoresGrid" top="10" bottom="10" width="426"
            creationComplete="proveedoresGrid.addEventListener('editIconClicked', itemRendererEditClickHandler);proveedoresGrid.addEventListener('deleteIconClicked', btn_eliminar_proveedor_clickHandler);"
            dataProvider="{proveedoresModel.modelo.arrayProveedores}"
            gridClick="editProveedor(event)"
            horizontalCenter="-255" requestedRowCount="4">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn                       headerText="Edit" width="50" itemRenderer="renderers.EditGridRender" rendererIsEditable="false"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="proveedor" headerText="Proveedor" width="370" editable="false"></s:GridColumn>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

Well, In the first column I have s itemrenderer that display two icons "Edit & Delete", and depending on the icon click, it dispatch an Event. The question is that such Datagrid has another general event "gridClick". Once I click on a cell from the first column, 'gridClick' event always work and and should work for any other cell not belonging to the first column.

How could I accomplish do this?

Thanks.

EDIT:

**The ItemRenderer**:

```
<s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" clipAndEnableScrolling="true"
                width="50" height="30">

<fx:Metadata>
    [Event(name="editIconClicked")]
</fx:Metadata>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import events.EditItemEvent;

        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.controls.DataGrid;
        override public function prepare(hasBeenRecycled:Boolean):void {}

        protected function btn_edit_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            event.stopPropagation();
            dispatchEvent(new Event("editIconClicked", true, true));
        }
        protected function btn_delete_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            event.stopPropagation();
            dispatchEvent(new Event("deleteIconClicked", true, true));
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:HGroup width="100%" height="24" top="3" gap="1">

    <s:Image id="btn_edit" horizontalCenter="0"
             source="@Embed('assets/images/edit_icon.png')"
             verticalCenter="0"
             click="btn_edit_clickHandler(event)"/>

    <s:Image id="btn_delete" horizontalCenter="0" 
             source="@Embed('assets/images/delete_icon.png')"
             verticalCenter="0"
             click="btn_delete_clickHandler(event)"/>

</s:HGroup>
```

Comment: Would you be more specific? What is your problem? Are the two events generated properly?

Comment: I want to be able to distinguish between gridClick event and the event from the itemRenderer launched when a cell from 1st column clicked. In this situation, both events launch.

Comment: But the events are different and you can distinguish between them through their names, can't you?

Comment: Could you post your ItemRenderer's code?

Comment: I can distinguish between them but the fact is that the two events are launched.  @Anton I have posted the ItemRenderer code.

Comment: If you click on the "edit" image in the first column you have two events (gridClick and editIconClicked). If you click any other cell you have only the gridClick event. Is it so? What is a real scenario which brings a problem to you? Excuse me I want realy to understand the issue. As you can see nobody tries to answer the question, I think nobody understood it.

Comment: When I click ob any other cell, only GridClick trigger, but my problem is when i click on the image, where the two events trigger and I want to prevent that GridClick execute in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least I could solve my issue.

I did not know that I could get the **columnIndex** when clicked the DataGrid and base on this, I could prevent that GridClick event run and in case the columnIndex were 0 it means that one of the two images were clicked.